# How to pass a views variable to a template using Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

After checking several similar threads I still fail to get it work. I want to pass a simple variable from my `views.py` to my `index.html` template. But the template displays the variable 'liga1' as it is in the frontend and the variable's value isn't passed.

These are my files:

**views.py**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

# Render different pages


def render_landing_page(request, template="index.html"):
    liga = ['1. Bundesliga', 'Premier League', 'La liga']
    return render(request, template, {'liga': liga})
```

**index.html** (only a snippet):

```
    <!-- Sidebar -->

    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">Dasocc</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="countries"><img src="{% static "images/germany.png" %}" alt="germany">{{ liga }}
```

**urls.py** // project dir

```
from dasocc_app import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.render_landing_page, name='landing_page'),
    url(r'^$', views.liga, name='liga'),
    url(r'^dasocc-app/', include('dasocc_app.urls')),
    url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**urls.py** // app dir

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from dasocc_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    #Where home is some random view from your dassocc-app
    url(r'^$', views.liga, name='liga')
    ]
```

No html output at the frontend for {{ liga }} variable in index.html template:

[image]

Related project structure:

[image]

Comment: Try installing django-debug-toolbar - you will be able to check which view is executed, which template is rendered and what it gets in context from view. This hould help you to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I only have one view so far...

Comment: It might be due to that you are passing a list, try to pass a string instead of a list, or iterate your list in the template.

Comment: @Phanti does iterating over the list work? Maybe like this: `{% for e in liga1 %} {{ e }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: @Ralf, hm no. It just displays the iterating text in the frontend. Might there be an error in the projects settings.py? I will include that into my post.

Comment: Are you maybe running the code accidentally directly from the file instead via 'http://localhost:8000'? Is your address in the browser starting with 'file://'?

Comment: this is my browsers url: http://localhost/dasocc_project/dasocc_app/templates/

Comment: @Phanti Is `BASE_DIR('dasocc_app/templates')` working in your settings? It gives a `TypeError` for me (`Python 3.6` and `Django 2.2`). Shouldn't it be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dasocc_app', 'templates')` instead?

Comment: @Ralf, I don't get an error myself and tried your code which seems to work as well though. But initial issue not solved. How could I maybe debug the html div to check why it isn't linked to the views.py. I still have {{ liga1 }} displayed at the frontend instead of the variables value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you have added your templates to your urls.py. Even though you haven't told us what URL you are going to, it is clear from the output that you are visiting the template address directly and not going to the URL that is served by the liga view.

Remove the templates from your URLs and add a URL which points to liga.

Comment: Thank you for yor input. I tried to adapt accordingly but it seems something is still wrong in my code. I changed it to `path('/dasocc_project/dasocc_app/templates/', include("dasocc_app.views"))` according to the path syntax `path(route, view)`

Comment: But that wasn't what I said at all. *Stop trying to reference templates in your URLs*. The only thing that goes in URLs are views.

Comment: Also from one of your comments you seem to be going to localhost/... which presumably is served directly by Apache and not by your Django server. Go to localhost:8000/...

Comment: I updated the codes and images.The project now runs in a virtualenv via localhost:8000 as suggested, thanks for the input. Additionally the issue mutated and now there is nothing displayed at the frontend (when i was on apache server it displayed the inserted variable as string).

Comment: But now you have two identical URLs pointing to different views. That can't work. Only `render_landing_page` will be called, and that doesn't send any data to the template.

Comment: Ok, now I got the problem. So I have to remove one url and make a single url point to multiple view functions in views.py to render more than one html objects?

Comment: I changed the views function (see post) and now it renders both the index.html landing page and the liga variable. Thank you very much for your continous efforts.